# SPSS Script from version 15 to version 20 in BASIC

Tags: vba, spss, basic, winwrap

The below script is written in 'Winwrap basic' which is almost identical to VBA.
I would like this script to work on SPSS 20, the script works fine on SPSS15 (by changing the file extension from STT to TLO as that is what the tablelook file was back then).

However, whenever I run this script in SPSS 20 the wwb processor crashes with a generic error message 'WWBProcessor has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.'

The script is well commented, but the purpose of the script is to change the tablelook of every table in the output viewer window, by activating each table in turn and setting the table look to one specified by the user, rotating the inner column labels, closing the table and activating the next table. 
The loop continues until every table has been set to the new tablelook and rotation.

Manually setting the rotation of a few hundred tables is arduous and very time consuming not to mention numbingly boring. This script used to perform this task in seconds back in version 15, but ever evolving needs and lack of support for the older version has meant that I've been forced to use the newer version.

I'd be grateful for any assistance.
Mav

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main
'BEGIN DESCRIPTION
'This script changes all tabs to the same 'Tablelook' style.  You will be prompted to choose the tablelook file.
'END DESCRIPTION
'******************
'Old description
'This script assumes that objSpssApp ist the currently running
'SPSS-Application and assigns every existing Pivot Table
'in the Output Navigator a new TableLook which can be selected
'from a Dialog box. Hidden tables will also be affected.
'Originally Created by SPSS Germany. Author: Arnd Winter.
'******************
'This script is written in the BASIC revision 'WinWrap Basic' code copied from VB or other basic languages may have to be modified to function properly.

On Error GoTo Bye

' Variable Declaration 
' For an undertermined reason scripts cannot be executed throught the Utilites -> Run scripts menu,
' Instead they must be opened like a syntax file and ran from the SPSS 19 Scripting page.
' Functionality on SPSS 20 is now completely gone, error message only reads 'WWB processor has encountered a problem and needs to close'.
Dim objOutputDoc As ISpssOutputDoc 'Declares the Output variable
Set objOutputDoc = objSpssApp.GetDesignatedOutputDoc 'Assigns currently active output to Output variable
Dim strAppPath As String
Dim objOutputItems As ISpssItems 'variable defining every item in the current output window
Dim objOutputItem As ISpssItem 'variable defining the current item
Dim objPivotTable As PivotTable
Dim intCount As Integer 'declare the variable that will store the number of instances
Dim varStrLook As String
Set objOutputItems=objOutputDoc.Items
Dim i As Integer 'for loops we need an INT variable that will be counted against the number of instances 'i' is standard notation
' Find out SPSS Directory 
strAppPath = objSpssApp.GetSPSSPath

' Select TableLook 

'The Parametres you must enter into the GetFilePath() function are as follows:
'(Optional)Firstly you enter the initial file name (if none is required use an asterisk * and the file extention, or *.*)
'(Optional)The second part is the file extention expected, you can choose multiple filetypes if you seperate them with a semi-colon ;
'(Optional)The third parametre is the directory where the file should be opened.(default - Current path)
'The fourth parametre is the Title of the prompt, which should be enclosed in speech marks.
'The Final parametre is the 'Option'
'0   Only allow the user to select a file that exists.
'1   Confirm creation when the user selects a file that does not exist.
'2   Allow the user to select any file whether it exists or not.
'3   Confirm overwrite when the user selects a file that exists.
'+4  Selecting a different directory changes the application's current directory.
'For more detailed information visit the WWB website.
' http://www.winwrap.com/web/basic/language/?p=doc_getfilepath__func.htm
varStrLook = GetFilePath$("*.stt","stt",strAppPath,"Select Tablelook and confirm with Save.",4)
' Tested re-applying the dollar sign, cofusingly removing or adding the Dollar sign ($)
' seems to have no effect.

' If user presses Cancel or selected a file with the wrong file type then exit script
If (Len(varStrLook)= 0) Or (Right(varStrLook,3)<>"stt") Then 
    Exit Sub
End If

' Loop which assigns a new TableLook to all existing Tables.
intCount = objOutputItems.Count 'Assigns the total number of output items to the count-marker
For i = 0 To intCount-1 'Start loop
    Set objOutputItem=objOutputItems.GetItem(i) 'Get current item
    If objOutputItem.SPSSType=SPSSPivot Then 'If the item is a pivot table then...
        Set objPivotTable=objOutputItem.ActivateTable 'Activate the table for editing
        objPivotTable.TableLook = varStrLook 'Apply the earlier selected table look.
        objPivotTable.RotateColumnLabels=True 'Rotate collumn lables
        objOutputItem.Deactivate 'Confirm changes and deactivate the table
    End If 
Next 'End loop
'********************************************************
'Updated script from Version 15 ->
'Script now includes inner column label rotation
'Script has been modified and adapted to improve performance
'and to help people who wish to use/adapt the script
'in future endeavours.
'********************************************************
Bye:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is to replace the activate/deactivate calls with 
GetTableOLEObject
This is much more efficient and does not require the pivot table editor, but you can do all the things that you could do on an activated table.

If you don't have the current fixpack for V20, fixpack2, installing that would be a good idea, too.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? The documentation I have on that method says `When you get an object using this method, you can perform the tasks you usually do in the outline view. To edit the pivot table, use the ActivateTable method.`
So from what is written, it would seem that I'll still have to activate/deactivate the object regardless.

Comment: After some fiddling however I found which step the program jumps out on when I use the step into function of the script editor it gets to line 30, `Set objOutputItems=objOutputDoc.Items` I can see no problems with this line.